# bounded variation implies differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ be of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere.

I.e., the limit

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$

exists.

My idea: Since $F$ is of bounded variation, given any partition

$$a=t_0<...<t_N=b$$

there exists some $M \in (0,\infty)$ such that

$$\sum_{j=1}^N \bigg\vert F(t_j)-F(t_{j-1}) \bigg\vert \leq M$$

So can I use this and apply it to the numerator in the quotient up top? That is, take $x+h:=t_j,x:=t_{j-1}$
So if I can bound the numerator, does the limit exist?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115886/42969

Comment: This is a standard result which you can find in books on measure theory and integration.

Comment: @fwd do you have a text recommendation ?

Comment: Stein and Shakarchi, Real Analysis. Bogachev, Measure Theory

Comment: He doesn't prove this case in that text @fwd

Comment: This is Stein & Shakarchi Theorem 3.4

Comment: @fwd exactly, there's no proof for it in the text, he did not provide that with proof.

Comment: This is not something you want to prove without guidance.  But, to answer your question, your "idea" is not useful.  Instead, a first step would be realizing that if you can prove the theorem for all monotonic functions, then it follows for functions of bounded variation.  But bravo for trying.  Now consult some standard proofs and study them.  Don't miss the one that uses the *rising sun lemma*.